# Capitalizing the first letter in a string. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, string, methods, char

What am I doing wrong? When I run my program it only prints some of my string, and it does not capitalize the first letter..

```
public class StringTraining extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        String str = "halOOlOO";
        capitalize(str);
    }


    private String capitalize(String str){
        String s = "";
        char ch;
        for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(i==0 && Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                Character.toUpperCase(ch);
                s += ch;
                i++;
            } else {
                Character.toLowerCase(ch);
                s += ch;
                i++;
            }
        }
        println(s);
        return s;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to only capitalize the first letter and keep the rest of the string the same, or have only the first letter be capitalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should not increment `i` again in the loop since it will be done automatically in the signature of the loop.
2. You have to assign `Character.toUpperCase(ch)` to the `String` or append it.
3. I'd suggest you use a `StringBuilder` when looping to build a String object

---

**Correction**

```
private static String capitalize(String str){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;
    for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(i==0 && Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            s.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        } else {
            s.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        }
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

**Output**

```
Halooloo
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign the variable ch to the upper or lower case value:

```
for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(i==0 && Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            s += ch;
        } else {
            ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            s += ch;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove some unnecessary codes from your `capitalize(String)` method such as `i++` and use
`s += String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(ch));` code instead of

```
Character.toUpperCase(ch);
s += ch;
```

**Complete capitalize(String) method**

```
private static String capitalize(String str) {
    String s = "";
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0 && Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            s += String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        } else {
            s += String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        }
    }
    println(s);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) return a string, you need to assign it to `ch`.
You also need to increment your `i` only one time (in the `for`, and not in the `if`)

Answer (score 0):

Change your capitalize(String str) method like this -

```
 private static String capitalize(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    String caps = chars[0]+"";
    caps = caps.toUpperCase();
    String output = caps;
    for(int i=1;i<chars.length;i++) {
        output = output + chars[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Output :

```
HalOOlOO
```